# compile-time base64 converter

Tags: c++, c++20

I have always been amazed at the number of things you can do in a `constexpr` function, yet I have not thought much about them until recently when I found out that c++20 added the ability to pass user-defined types as a template parameter. Meaning there is a way to pass strings as a template parameter which made me think couldn't you make a compile-time base64 encoder. As a result, I decided to make a compile-time base 64 encoder.

Here is the code:
`base64.cc`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
namespace base64
{
template <std::size_t N>
struct FixedString
{
    char buf[N + 1] {};
    constexpr FixedString() = default;
    constexpr FixedString(char const *s)
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i)
            buf[i] = s[i];
    }
    template <std::size_t S>
    constexpr FixedString(FixedString<S> const &other)
    {
        for (std::size_t i = (S > N ? N : S); i--;)
            buf[i] = other.buf[i];
    }
    auto constexpr operator == (FixedString const &other) const
    {
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            if(buf[i]!=other[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    constexpr operator char const *() const { return buf; }
    constexpr operator char *() { return buf; }
    std::size_t constexpr size() const { return N; }
};

template <std::size_t N>
FixedString(char const (&)[N]) -> FixedString < N - 1 >;

template <FixedString string>
auto constexpr decode()
{
    std::size_t constexpr string_size = string.size();
    auto constexpr find_padding = [string_size]() {
        std::size_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < string_size; ++i)
            if (string[i] == '=')
                break;
        return i;
    };
    FixedString <find_padding() * 3 / 4 > result;
    auto constexpr convert_char = [](auto const & ch) {
        if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
            return ch - 65;
        else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
            return ch - 71;
        else if (ch >= '0')
            return ch + 4;
        else
            return ch == '+' ? 62 : 63;
    };
    for (std::size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < string_size; i += 4, j += 3)
    {
        char bytes[3] = {
            static_cast<char>(convert_char(string[i]) << 2
            | convert_char(string[i + 1]) >> 4),
            static_cast<char>(convert_char(string[i + 1]) << 4
            | convert_char(string[i + 2]) >> 2),
            static_cast<char>(convert_char(string[i + 2]) << 6
            | convert_char(string[i + 3])),
        };
        result[j] = bytes[0];
        result[j + 1] = bytes[1];
        if (string[i + 3] != '=')
            result[j + 2] = bytes[2];
    }
    return result;
}

template <FixedString string>
auto constexpr encode()
{
    std::size_t constexpr string_size = string.size();
    std::size_t constexpr result_size_no_padding = (string_size * 4 + 2) / 3;
    std::size_t constexpr result_size = (result_size_no_padding + 3) & (-4);
    std::size_t constexpr padding_size = result_size - result_size_no_padding;
    FixedString <(string_size + 2) / 3 * 3> constexpr string_with_padding = string;
    FixedString<result_size> result;
    auto constexpr convert_num = [](auto const & num) {
        if (num < 26)
            return static_cast<char>(num + 65);
        else if (num > 25 && num < 52)
            return static_cast<char>(num + 71);
        else if (num > 51)
            return static_cast<char>(num - 4);
        else
            return num == 62 ? '+' : '/';
    };
    for (std::size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < string_size; i += 3, j += 4)
    {
        /* convert every 3 bytes to 4 6 bit numbers
         * 8 * 3 = 24
         * 6 * 4 = 24
         */
        char bytes[4] = {
            static_cast<char>(string_with_padding[i] >> 2),
            static_cast<char>((string_with_padding[i]
            & 3) << 4
            | string_with_padding[i + 1] >> 4),
            static_cast<char>((string_with_padding[i + 1] & 15) << 2
            | string_with_padding[i + 2] >> 6),
            static_cast<char>(string_with_padding[i + 2] & 63)
        };
        result[j] = convert_num(bytes[0]);
        result[j + 1] = convert_num(bytes[1]);
        result[j + 2] = convert_num(bytes[2]);
        result[j + 3] = convert_num(bytes[3]);
    }
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < padding_size; ++i)
        result[result_size_no_padding + i] = '=';
    return result;
}
} // namespace base64

/* here is a test */
int main()
{

    auto constexpr input_text = base64::FixedString { "Man is distinguished, not only by his reason, but by this singular passion from other animals, \
which is a lust of the mind, that by a perseverance of delight in the continued and indefatigable \
generation of knowledge, exceeds the short vehemence of any carnal pleasure."};
    auto constexpr encoded = base64::encode<input_text>();
    auto constexpr decoded = base64::decode<encoded>();
    static_assert(decoded == input_text);
    std::cout << encoded << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall the code is quite well written, and it's an interesting program.

1. The biggest improvement that I think can be made is avoiding all the raw loops. From c++20, many of the algorithms are `constexpr`, which means the following member functions could be one liners:

```
constexpr FixedString(char const* s)
{
    std::copy(s, s + N, buf);
}

template <std::size_t S>
constexpr FixedString(FixedString<S> const& other)
{
    std::copy(other.buf, other.buf + std::min(S, N), buf);
}

auto constexpr operator==(FixedString const& other) const
{
    return std::equal(buf, buf + N, other.buf);
}
```

There is a similar example in the `decode` function, where the `find_padding` lambda could be:

```
auto constexpr find_padding = [string_size]() {
    return std::distance(string.buf, 
               std::find(string.buf, string.buf + string_size, '='));
};
```

and in the `encode` function, this code:

```
result[j] = convert_num(bytes[0]);
result[j + 1] = convert_num(bytes[1]);
result[j + 2] = convert_num(bytes[2]);
result[j + 3] = convert_num(bytes[3]);
```

could be replaced by the shorter:

```
std::transform(bytes, bytes + 4, result.buf + j, convert_num);
```

and this loop:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < padding_size; ++i)
    result[result_size_no_padding + i] = '=';
```

could be replaced by:

```
std::fill_n(result.buf + result_size_no_padding, padding_size, '=');
```

2. You have used clear names for all your variables, and functions, but snippets like the following:

```
if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
```

should be named as well (even if it's used in only one place). Ideally, you would use `std::isupper`, but it's not `constexpr`, so that's not possible. However, it's trivial to write your own named function that is `constexpr`. In particular, it would be much more readable to have names for snippets like:

```
if (num > 25 && num < 52)
```

for example, something like `reverse_is_upper` would make sense?

3. As it stands, I find the `encode` and `decode` functions a little long (though this is reduced by removing the raw loops). Still, the lambda expressions could be moved out of the `*code` functions and used as needed.
4. This is a relatively minor point, but I'm not a fan of the implicit conversions to `char*` from `FixedString`. The primary advantage seems to be that you avoid having to write `.buf` everywhere, but the negative impacts of implicit conversions outweigh this benefit (as the code increases, it becomes increasingly easy to make a subtle mistake because of this). Also, it's being used in `main` to allow streaming like this:

```
std::cout << encoded << '\n';
```

but this is better solved by overloading `operator<<` for `FixedString` instead.